# Builder Pattern for Collection of Heterogeneous Items

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I'm trying to figure out the proper way to set up a builder for a collection of heterogeneous items (in data, not type).

Suppose I have a peg board that I want to construct. The pegboard contains a vector of `Pegs` each with a set of coordinates. The pegs also have a color, and a bunch of other POD properties.

I am implementing the builder pattern to construct different `PegBoards` but I am unsure of how to treat the following issues:

- In some cases I may want to take one or two pegs, and tell the builder to make *n* copies of them and randomly place them onto the pegboard.
- In other cases I may want to explicitly provide a vector of pegs with initialized positions, and properties.
- I may want to create a Pegboard with 50% red pegs, 50% blue pegs, or 20% red pegs and 80% blue pegs, etc... My understanding is that with the builder pattern I am stuck making concrete builders for each of the (infinite) possible combinations I want.

Essentially, I like the methodical way the Builder pattern constructs objects, but I need to have some flexibility in the building process as well. Should I have methods in my director such as `SetPegColors(vector colors, vector ratios)`. Who's responsibility is it? Should I keep those methods in my PegBoard and call them if I need to after the building process?

Or is the Builder pattern not the answer to constructing a `Pegboard` the way I would like?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you are using **Builder** because you want the pegs to be created and placed into the `PegBoard` at the time of creation, not to be modified later. It is a good use case for **Builder** pattern. In this case providing a method like `setPegColors(..)` would break the design. It looks like you need a  `PegCreationStrategy` in the Builder. Something like this (Java syntax):

```
public interface PegCreationStrategy {
   Peg[] getPegs(int n);
}

public class PrototypePegCreationStrategy {
    public PrototypePegCreationStrategy(Peg[] prototypes) {
    }

    @Override Peg[] getPegs(int n) {
    }
}

public class ColorRatioPegCreationStrategy {
    public ColorRatioPegCreationStrategy(vector colors, vector ratios) {
    }

    @Override Peg[] getPegs(int n) {
    }
}

public class PegBoard {
  public static class Builder {
    private int numPegs;
    private PegCreationStrategy strategy;
    Build withNumPegs(numPegs) {...}
    Builder withPegCreationStrategy(PegCreationStrategy s) {...}
    Builder withSomeOtherProperty(...) { ... }
    PegBoard build() { 
       Peg[] pegs = strategy.getPegs(numPegs);
       ...// other properties
       return new PegBoard(...);
  }
}

public static void main() {
    PegBoard pb = new PegBoard.Builder()
                    .withPegCreationStrategy(new ColorRatioPegCreationStrategy())
                    .withNumPegs(10)
                    .withSomeOtherProperty(...)
                    .build();
}
```